# Crystal Reports DLL crashing program

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having a hard time getting a .NET C# app to work after changing a DB password.  Since then, it crashes when entering Crystal reports functionality that used to work.  This problem does not occur when running in 'debug mode' in visual studio.  However, I can get it to occur in the debugger by running the debug executable from the command line and then attaching the VS debugger to that process before clicking the button that causes the crash.  I can follow the code and see that there are no uninitialized variables causing this crash.  Rather it appears that a malformed object is being created when constructing the Crystal reports viewer.

90% of the issues I've had with this application in the past 6 years have been due to Crystal Reports.  I'm pr